# Tradingview pinescript- 3M timeframe support & resistance plots

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

Using tradingview Pinescript I'd like to plot horizontal lines on the high/low for a specified number of bars from the '3M' timeframe to be viewed on any timeframe. The code works when viewed on the '3M' timeframe. However when going down to a lower timeframe an issue arises. Some of the support/resistance lines don't show up.

```
//@version=5
indicator("3M-HLINE", overlay=true)

// Define the timeframe
timeframe1 =input.timeframe('3M', "Timeframe")

// Calculate the number of bars to look back
numBarsBack1 =input.int(16,"BARS BACK")

// Arrays to store open and close values
var float[] openArr1 = array.new_float(numBarsBack1)
var float[] closeArr1 = array.new_float(numBarsBack1)

array.clear(openArr1)
array.clear(closeArr1)

baropen1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe1, high)
barclose1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe1, low)

// Accumulate 3M open/close values in arrays
for i = 1 to numBarsBack1
    array.unshift(openArr1, baropen1[i])
    array.unshift(closeArr1, barclose1[i])

// Plot the 3M open/close values as lines
for i = 0 to numBarsBack1 -1
    line.new(x1=bar_index - 1, y1=array.get(openArr1, i), x2=bar_index + 1, y2=array.get(openArr1, i), color=color.new(color.rgb(135, 206, 250), 0), width=2, extend=extend.both)
    line.new(x1=bar_index - 1, y1=array.get(closeArr1, i), x2=bar_index + 1, y2=array.get(closeArr1, i), color=color.new(color.rgb(135, 206, 250), 0), width=2, extend=extend.both)`
```

1. I tried putting the "request.security" inside the for loop. The script doesn't allow that.
2. I tried using hline to plot. Cannot be used with the float array.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//@version=5
indicator("3M-HLINE", overlay=true)

// Define the timeframe
timeframe1 =input.timeframe('3M', "Timeframe")

// Calculate the number of bars to look back
numBarsBack1 =input.int(16,"BARS BACK")

myFun()=>
    // Arrays to store open and close values
    var float[] openArr1 = array.new_float(numBarsBack1)
    var float[] closeArr1 = array.new_float(numBarsBack1)

    array.clear(openArr1)
    array.clear(closeArr1)
    // Accumulate 3M open/close values in arrays
    for i = 1 to numBarsBack1
        array.unshift(openArr1, high[i])
        array.unshift(closeArr1, low[i])
    [openArr1, closeArr1]

[closeArr1, openArr1] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe1, myFun())



if not na(openArr1) and not na(closeArr1)
    for i = 0 to numBarsBack1 -1
        line.new(x1=bar_index - 1, y1=array.get(openArr1, i), x2=bar_index + 1, y2=array.get(openArr1, i), color=color.new(color.rgb(135, 206, 250), 0), width=2, extend=extend.both)
        line.new(x1=bar_index - 1, y1=array.get(closeArr1, i), x2=bar_index + 1, y2=array.get(closeArr1, i), color=color.new(color.rgb(135, 206, 250), 0), width=2, extend=extend.both)
```